# How to get combine string list from list object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of location with ID and Name like

```
public class Dim_Location
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string LocationName{ get; set; }
    public string ClienId{ get; set; }
}  

private List<string> loadLocation(int clientIdx)
{
    List<Dim_Location> LocationList = dim_Location.GetLocation(clientIdx);
      //Combine here List<ID+";"+LocationName> and make List<string>
}
```

Now I want get `List<ID+";"+LocationName>` from `LocationList`.

Comment: What problems did you run into when attempting to solve this problem on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = LocationList.Select(x => x.ID + ";" + x.LocationName);
```